# Get a value from clicked button display it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-state

**Hi,**

I'm learning React and creating a vehicle configurator. I ran into a problem and I don't know how to fix it. In the application, we have 4 fields to choose from: model, engine, gearbox and the color we can choose for our car.

```
const [carModel, setCarModel] = useState("");
const [carEngine, setCarEngine] = useState("");
const [carGearbox, setCarGearbox] = useState("");
const [carColor, setCarColor] = useState("");
```

All types of cars, engines, gearboxes are written here:

```
const ModelsTypes = [
        {model: "pro rs3"},
        {model: "uber rs2"},
        {model: "standard"},
        {model: "wk"},
]

const EngineTypes = [
        {engine: "5.2l 532bhp"},
        {engine: "4.2l 443bhp"},
        {engine: "3.6 374bhp"},
        {engine: "2.0 166bhp"},
]

const Gearbox = [
        {gearbox: "Manual"},
        {gearbox: "Automatic"},
]
```

In the main component of my application, I am returning all the results

```
{ModelsTypes.map(model =>
 <Button value={model.model} text={model.model} />
)}

{EngineTypes.map(engine=>
 <Button value={engine.engine} text={engine.engine} />
)}

{Gearbox.map(gearbox =>
 <Button value={gearbox.gearbox} text={gearbox.gearbox} />
)}
```

`Button.js`

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import styles from "./Button.module.scss";

export const Button = ({text}) => {

    const [switchToggled, setSwitchToggled] = useState(false);

    const PickItem = () => {
        switchToggled ? setSwitchToggled(false) : setSwitchToggled(true);
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={PickItem} className={switchToggled ? `${styles.buttonClicked}` : `${styles.button}`}>
            {text}
        </button>
    )
}
```

After selecting the option, all results should be displayed in the summary:

```
<ul>
 <li>Model: <span>{carModel}</span></li>
 <li>Engine: <span>{carEngine}</span></li>
 <li>Gearbox: <span>{carGearbox}</span></li>
 <li>Color: <span>{carColor}</span></li>
</ul>
```

I would like the user to be able to select only one field in each option, and if a selection is made the user will still be able to select and change options, but only the latest user selection can be saved in useState.

Comment: Seems like a good use case for radio controls. You can style them to appear like buttons if needed but since browser only allows one of each group selected seems like this would help you

Comment: Oh, I tried to use the radio but there was a problem because I can check many options anyway. Isn't that because my Button is a separate component and each Button has a separate state?

Comment: You probably didn't use a common `name` for each radio within each group. That's what browser uses to know what is allowed to be checked

Comment: Now I can see I haven't actually passed the name to my component. Can I still count on help, how can I pass the value from the button to useState?